# $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and there is an integer $m$ that divides $n$.Prove that there is a subgroup of $G$ of order $\frac{n}{m}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

$G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and there is an integer $m$ that divides $n$.
Prove that there is a subgroup of $G$ of order $\frac{n}{m}$.

Can I use Lagrange's theorem to help with this proof?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a generator of $G$.  $x^m$ generates  a subgroup of order $n/m$

Comment: why does that imply the order is n/m? I get that x is an element that when raised to consecutive powers will create all elements in the group.

Comment: $(x^m)^{n/m}=x^n=e$, we deduce that the order$l$  of $x^m$ is inferior or equal to $n/m$, if $l<n/m, (x^m)^l=x^{lm}=e$ implies that the order of $x$ is $lm<n$ contradiction.